# How to marshal Null objects from .NET to COM as an object type?

Tags: .net, marshalling, com-interop

In the middle of a large project that is using COM interop while migrating from VB6 to .NET, I found the need to write code that receives an object from an interop method and then pass that object into an interop form when then object is not null.

I discovered [on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2x07fbw8%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) that null objects are returned as an Empty variant. This causes a problem with VB6 code like this, where validator is the interop class and inputKey is irrelevant to the issue.

```
Set validationObject = validator.GetValidationList(inputKey)
```

The Set statement cannot be used when the variant is Empty. Here's a sample of what the function was doing.

```
    Dim validationList = GetValidationList(inputKey)
    If validationList IsNot Nothing AndAlso validationList.Count > 0 Then
        Return validationList
    Else
        Return Nothing
    End If
```

Is there a best practice for how to get the Null value returned to COM as VT_OBJECT variant? Is the following code a good idea? It seems to work, but is it the "right" way to do this?

```
    Dim validationList = GetValidationList(inputKey)
    If validationList IsNot Nothing AndAlso validationList.Count > 0 Then
        Return validationList
    Else
        Return New System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnknownWrapper(Nothing)
    End If
```

Comment: I'm assuming that this VB.NET code is in a library, and the client code using it is VB6. Is that correct?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I'll be able to help without being able to recreate the problem. I have a C# library manually rigged for COM interop (defined interfaces and GUIDs myself) in one my shop's projects, and returning `null` works just fine. Could you give information on the type that `GetValidationList()` returns?

Comment: At it's core ValidationList is a .NET class. The original code was returning a VT_OBJECT variant in the positive case and VT_EMPTY variant in the negative case (i.e. Return Nothing). That causes problems in VB6 because you have to use a different syntax to assign those two variant types.

Comment: Could have to do with how your .NET object is exposed to COM. In OLE Object Viewer (windows sdk) you'll be able to look at the IDL for the typelib. What does it show for `GetValidationList()`? Also, what attributes have you used on the `Validator` class to control how it is exposed to COM?

Answer (score 1):

The list from MSDN you posted also seem to reveal that `System.DBNull` will match to `VT_NULL`.

The MSDN page of [System.DBNull](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dbnull.aspx) seems to support this further:

`Additionally, COM interop uses the DBNull class to distinguish between a VT_NULL variant, which indicates a nonexistent value, and a VT_EMPTY variant, which indicates an unspecified value.`

Comment: This doesn't really help the described problem because the VT_NULL is a value type and has the same problem as when VT_EMPTY is returned. I have reworded the problem to try and make the request clearer.